# Access PHP class files outside DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: php, apache, structure

I am confused as to what constitutes "
best practice" for the structure of a PHP web-based application.  Reading this site there are a number of suggestions.  One structure frequently mentioned is "do not have any php files inside the document root".  While this sounds like good practice, I cannot see how it works - the web server doesn't recognise anything outside the document root.  I assume here that document root is the public access directory, something like as shown below:

```
app-
  |
  - htdocs - document root
  | |
  | - index.php
  | - css/
  | - images/
  |
  - PHP classes in here/
  - Other PHP classes in here.../
```

Or is it that "app" in the above example is the document root, and the **htdocs** dir is the publicly accessible area of the site structure?

Following on from that, how do I ensure public access is not available for the files in dirs other than **htdocs** please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept is simple, especially if you use a front controller based framework whether it be your own or an existing one (like the Zend Framework). When all of the requests come through a central controller the files necessary to handle the request are included as necessary. Included files do not have to be in the web root to work. They just need to be available to the controller to be included and then executed. So, only your controller needs to be in the web root. Everything else can be outside of it.

FYI, this also works with non-OOP applications. You just need to include the files you need in  each page.

What does need to be in the web root are any asests like images, styelsheets, javascript files, etc. that are requested by the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! I do not use the **include** statement in my OOP app.  I use **require_once**.  Each of my classes, where necessary, have require_once statements.  Will this effect the ability of a controller as you describe from accessing the classes required?

Comment: Nope. They fundamentally do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try your solution, and get back with the results of that.

Comment: Ok - I've implemented and tested this solution.  It certainly works as expected.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

While it's true the webserver won't recognize anything "outside" the document root, that only applies to files requested by the **USER** via an HTTP request.

PHP runs within the webserver, and has no concept of document roots and URLs. it sees only the underlying file system of the webserver's host operating system, and data coming in and going out that conforms to certain standards. The only time PHP would be bound by some web-based restriction is if the webserver itself is running within a chroot jail.

As such, you can put a php file **ANYWHERE** on the file system, and, assuming permissions are correct, PHP will be able to reach it and run it. It doesn't matter if that file is buried in a directory 500 levels deep somewhere completely outside the document root - if it's reachable, PHP can run it.

Comment: Ah yes - this is similar in concept to the answer posted above.  As long as any user-based request resolves to the document root, then all should be well.  Thank you for the added information.  I have not had the opportunity to get back to this yet, but I will let you know how a solution based on your comments (and the comments above) goes.